# Cómo obtener datos de un DataGridView e insertarlos en los TextBox de otro formulario?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Necesito obtener los datos de un `DataGridView` de una base datos para insertarlos en los `TextBox` de otro formulario, tal que al abrir el formulario, los datos se ingresen automáticamente para modificarles y guardar los cambios.

Este es el código que tengo en mi proyecto:

**Clase `Film`:** Es la clase con la que represento películas en mi programa.

```
public class Film
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public Film() { }

    public Film (Int64 Id, string Title, string Country, string Gender)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.Title = Title;
        this.Country = Country;
        this.Gender = Gender;
    }
}
```

---

**Clase `FilmDAL`:** Es la clase que me permite obtener los datos de la pelicula seleccionada y el método para modificar.

```
public class FilmDAL
{
    public static Film GetFilm(Int64 pId)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = Connection.GetConnection())
        {
            Film pFilm = new Film();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT Id, Title, Country, Gender FROM Films WHERE Id={0}", pId), con);

            try
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    pFilm.Id = reader.GetInt64(0);
                    pFilm.Title = reader.GetString(1);
                    pFilm.Country = reader.GetString(2);
                    pFilm.Gender = reader.GetString(3);
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            con.Close();
            return pFilm;
        }
    }

    public static int Modify(Film pFilm)
    {
        int rturn = 0;
        using (SqlConnection con = Connection.GetConnection())
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("UPDATE Films SET Title='{0}', Country='{1}', Gender='{2}' WHERE Id={3}", pFilm.Title, pFilm.Country, pFilm.Gender, pFilm.Id), con);

            rturn = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return rturn;

    }
}
```

---

**Form `Redact`:** Es el formulario donde se encuentra el `DataGridView`.

```
public partial class Redact : Form
{
    public Redact()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CenterToScreen();
    }

    private void buttonRedactFilm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
        {
            Int64 Id = Convert.ToInt64(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
            RedactFilm rf = new RedactFilm();
            rf.ShowDialog();
            SelectedFilm = FilmDAL.GetFilm(Id);
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Seleccione una película.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
}
```

---

**Form RedactFilm:**  Es el formulario en el cual, al abrirlo, deben estar escritos los datos de la película seleccionada para poder modificarlos.

```
public partial class RedactFilm : Form
{

    public RedactFilm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CenterToScreen();
    }

    public Film CurrentFilm { get; set; }

    private void RedactFilm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Redact redact = new Redact();
        if (redact.SelectedFilm != null)
        {
            CurrentFilm = redact.SelectedFilm;
            textBox1.Text = redact.SelectedFilm.Title;
            textBox2.Text = redact.SelectedFilm.Country;
            textBox3.Text = redact.SelectedFilm.Gender;
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Film pFilm = new Film();
        pFilm.Title = textBox1.Text;
        pFilm.Country = textBox2.Text;
        pFilm.Gender = textBox3.Text;
        pFilm.Id = CurrentFilm.Id;

        int result = FilmDAL.Modify(pFilm);

        if (result > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Película modificada!", "Mensaje", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al modificar", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Cómo obtener datos del `DataGridView` e insertarlos en los `TextBox` del formulario `RedactFilm`?

Comment: De un vistazo aquí: http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2014/05/comunicar-formularios.html

Comment: Quiero suponer que es windows form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder tomar los valores del `DataGridView` de un formulario y pasarlo a otro formulario te recomiendo que uses el constructor del formulario receptor para eso o la asignación directa de valores a las variables miembros de la clase del formulario que contiene los `TextoBox` (`RedactFilm`).

> ### Utilizando el constructor del formulario:
>
> Esta es la solución de tu caso utilizando el constructor del
>   formulario `RedactFilm`:
>
> ```
> public partial class RedactFilm : Form 
> {
>
>     public Film CurrentFilm { get; set; }
>
>     // Si te da algún error se debe a que necesitas
>     // un constructor sin argumentos para esta clase.
>     // En caso que te salga, descomentas está parte.
>     /*public RedactFilm() 
>     { 
>         InitializeComponent(); 
>         this.CenterToScreen();
>      }*/
>
>     public RedactFilm(Film CurrentFilm = new Film()) 
>     { 
>         InitializeComponent(); 
>         this.CenterToScreen();
>         this.CurrentFilm = CurrentFilm;
>      }
>      ...
> }
> ```
>
> De esta manera ya podrás pasar el objeto de la clase `Film` desde que
>   instancias un formulario de esta clase, así como lo haces en tu método
>   `buttonRedactFilm_Click()` en tu clase `Redact`:
>
> ```
> // Instancias tu formulario y pasas la película como parámetro.
> RedactFilm rf = new RedactFilm(FilmDAL.GetFilm(Id));
> rf.ShowDialog();
> ```
>
> Y luego deberás tener alguna manera de tomar los atributos de tu
>   objeto `Film` y escribirlos en los `TextBox` de tu formulario
>   `RedactFilm`. He notado que en tu método `RedactFilm_Load()` ya lo
>   haces.
>
> ### Asignar el valor directamente a la variable miembro:
>
> También puedes crear una variable miembro de la clase `RedactFilm`,
>   para que escribas el valor de sus variables miembros en los `TextBox`.
>
> Por ejemplo:
>
> ```
> public partial class RedactFilm : Form 
> {
>     // Creas la variable miembro.
>     public Film CurrentFilm { get; set; }
>     ...
>
>     private void RedactFilm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         // Validas que el valor de la variable no sea nulo.
>         if (this.CurrentFilm != null)
>         {
>             // Escribes en los TextBox el contenido del objeto CurrentFilm.
>             textBox1.Text = this.CurrentFilm.Title;
>             textBox2.Text = this.CurrentFilm.Country;
>             textBox3.Text = this.CurrentFilm.Gender;
>         }
>
>     }
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> El valor de `CurrentFilm` se asignaría de la siguiente manera:
>
> ```
> // Instancias el formulario.
> RedactFilm rf = new RedactFilm();
> rf.CurrentFilm = FilmDAL.GetFilm(Id);
> rf.ShowDialog();
> ```
>
> De esta manera la variable miembro tendrá un valor y cuando se cargue
>   el formulario y se ejecute el método `RedactFilm_Load()`, se escriban
>   los valores del objeto `CurrentFilm` en los `TextBox`.

Answer (score 3):

Podrías hacer algo asi:

En donde esta tu dataGridView puedes pasar los parametros utilizando el constructor.

Ejemplo:
En Redact:

```
Int64 Id = Convert.ToInt64(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
String Title = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

Obtienes el ID y el Titulo.
Ahora cuando haces esto:

```
RedactFilm rf = new RedactFilm();
rf.ShowDialog();
```

Alli puedes mandar los parametros por el constructor

```
RedactFilm rf = new RedactFilm(Id, Title);
```

Y Para recibirlos en RedactFilm bastara con agregar un constructor que reciba los parametros(En este caso 2 parametros)

```
public RedactFilm(Int64 Id, string Title)
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.CenterToScreen();
  }
```

Ahora ya los pasamos, para usarlos bastara asignarlos a los textBox

```
textBox1.Text = Title;
```

Esta es una forma de pasar valores entre formularios, por medio del constructor puedes pasar los parametros. este ejemplo Solo pasamos el Id y el Title, puedes modificarlo para pasar mas parametros.

Un formulario puede tener mas de un constructor, los parametros que recibe hace que se diferencien.